# PySAM import failure on python3.11 macbookPro M2

Tags: installation, pysam

I am working with a macbook Pro M2, I have installed pyhton3. 11, and I have installed PySAM using "pip install PySAM" in the terminal. However, I cannot use and import PySAM in my python environment. I have tried it with jupyter and visual studio code.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled it, and also double checked the installation of numpy and pandas. I have also tried python3.10, but it didn't work.
Please help me figure it out!
Thanks